# How can I prevent MacBook Pro from connecting to Wi-Fi while it is asleep?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

My MacBook Pro connects to my mobile phone when it is in sleep mode. If my hotspot is enabled it begins using data and I'd rather not have to remove the paraphrase for the hotspot every time I make it sleep. How can this behavior be disabled or prevented?

Comment: Can you just turn off wifi before putting into a sleep?

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences, select the Energy Saver pane, uncheck Enable Power Nap on both the Battery and Power Adapter tabs.